# Casting System.Windows.Forms.Label to a custom type

Tags: c#, winforms, casting

I'm having a class where I'm deriving from System.Windows.Forms.Control

```
[Serializable]  
public class CommonControl : System.Windows.Forms.Control,IXmlSerializable 
{
```

Basically this class adds some more properties to the default Controls class.
My problem is I cannot cast the Control objects into my custom control objects. Since the customcontrol class is derived from Controls I thought it might work.

I'm doing the casting like this.

```
CommonControl ctrlTemp = new CommonControl();
ctrlTemp = (CommonControl)((Control)ctrl);
```

Here the ctrl is a Label object. When I debug the first casting works fine.
`(Control)ctrl` part. But when the `(CommonControl)((Control)ctrl)` is debugged it displays following message.

> (CommonControl)(ctrl) Cannot cast
>   'ctrl' (which has an actual type of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Label') to
>   'SharpFormEditorDemo.CommonControl'   SharpFormEditorDemo.CommonControl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot cast across class hierarchies. `Label` and `CommonControl` both inherit from `Control` but are distinct sibling classes, and thus you cannot cast one to the other, not even through their parent.

Or to put it more simply: once you create a `Label` object, it's always a `Label` object even if you cast it to use it as a `Control`. By casting it to `CommonControl` you're changing its type completely, which is illegal in C#.

There is no multiple inheritance either. As a workaround, you can make an interface, then create subclasses of the controls that you need to use that all implement your custom interface. A quick and dirty example:

```
public interface ICommonControl : System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable {
    // ...
}

[Serializable]
public class MyLabel : System.Windows.Forms.Label, ICommonControl {
    // Implement your common control interface and serializable methods here
}
```

Then creating `ctrl` as a `MyLabel` object. It inherits from `Label` and adopts all the interface methods defined by your class. If you need to cast it, cast it to an `ICommonControl`.

Yes, you need to subclass each control class, but it's just one solution I can think of.

Comment: Thnx alot. I should've considered the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Oh God, do you know what you are doing?
ctrl is Label and definitely it is not in hierarcy between CommonControl and Control.
You should change ctrl type to your user define type in between CommonControl and Control hierarchy, then it will work.

Casting ctrl to Control is definitely okay, since Label derived from Control. However casting ctrl to CommonControl is definitely wrong, since ctrl by no means have any relationship with CommonControl

What you can do is create a class derived from Label, and make ctrl to create an object of that class. And that class is implementing the interface you want.

Comment: "Oh God, do you know what you are doing?" - There is no need for that!

Comment: @geoff - Thumbs Up :) Even though I value all the answers.. BTW it's a bit stupid thing I have done... :D Thnx everyone.

Comment: sorry to be rude... i am sorry... but actually you can pick up 1 or 2 books about Object Oriented Programming in C#, hopes it can help you understand why OO and help you in OO design of your program. Basically in you case you can also create a class that accept any Control object then check the actual type using is operator, and do serialization based on that... sorry again...

Comment: I upvoted this, even though I cringed a little bit at the first sentence. You're on the right track, and there's nothing wrong with the rest of your explanation. I even had the same initial reaction as you did, but I've learned it's best we try to contain our surprise when answering questions here. :-)